# Python: Создание Word документов по шаблону

Tags: python, python-3.x, office, docx

Задача скрипта открыть шаблон документа Word (dot, doc, docx). найти специально помеченные значения вида {change-this1}, заменить их (в тех же стилях что и был  заменяемый текст). Сохранить документ в формат пригодный для печати  и редактирования желательно  doc \ docx.

Вопрос: какие библиотеки/встроенные возможности python лучше всего подходят для данной задачи. Как я понимаю формат закрытый и просто "открытием" файла как "текста" дело не обойдется.

UPD: Нашел библиотеку которая кажется умеет открывать Word документы http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/ пока что изучаю её возможности.

Comment: Да, `python-docx` для вашей задачи подходит. На SO есть несколько похожих вопросов, например, [вот](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979864/5980797) пример поиска по документу

Answer (score 2):

Есть библиотека - [`python-docx-template`](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template), цель которой и заключается в том, чтобы создавать `.docx` документы с использованием [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/) шаблонов.

Устанавливается командой `pip install docxtpl`.

Используется - создаете документ (не HTML шаблон, а docx документ) как обычно, но на место переменных вставляете `{{ <var_name> }}` Jinja2 теги. Затем:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("my_template.docx")
context = { 'var_name' : "HELLO WORLD!" }
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated.docx")
```

Результат - в сгенерированном документе теги будут заменены нужными значениями.

Область применения довольно ограничена, но тем не менее в некоторых случаях может оказаться удобным.

Answer (score 1):

Старые бинарные `.doc` форматы даже разные версии MS Word могут по-разному  понимать (хорошо выглядит в одном месте—ломается в другом). Простой способ автоматизировать работу с Word-документами, если MS Word доступен—это выполнить пример руками в Ворде и записать его как VBA-макрос, который можно легко в Питон транслировать, если необходимо, например: [using win32com.client in python how to find and replace multiple text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16585952/4279).

Чтобы не зависеть от Ворда, если есть возможность, то лучше в рамках `.docx` формата остаться и попробовать упомянутый в вопросе пакет [`python-docx`](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/).